# Should I tell the new hiring manager about last short probation period?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

After a long search of several months (with multiple companies), finally got a job offer from company A. I accepted the offer and started working yesterday. Primarily because pay is pretty good and the deadline to accept the offer was about to expire.

To add to the confusion, yesterday company B extended an offer.

This happened because while I was waiting for paperwork for A to get sorted out, I casually interviewed at company B. In reality while I was interviewing with B, I hadn't really accepted the offer from A. I really didn't think B would give an offer when I finally accepted A's offer.

So now I have started working with company A and an offer for B is in the works.

I think I would like to work for Company B if everything checks out. But the primary reason to join company B is because it gives sponsorship to work in the UK after couple of months. Sure sounds promising from their side. Alas, their pay is 13K below what A provides, but I need to think long term.

A on the other hand hasn't really confirmed anything about sponsorship to work in the UK. They are still 'waiting for business to reply.'

So looks like I might join company B after a short stint with A.

My question is:

- Should I tell the hiring manger/internal recruiter from company B about this short stint (lets say 1-2 weeks) with company A? I am only seeing it as business and hope they would too.
- Would slightly negotiating hurt my chances with B if I were to tell
  them the truth? (I am not trying to cause a bidding war)
- Could I hide this fact from company B & proceed?

NB: This is my first job in the UK, and I am only trying to do what's right for me.

TLDR: Joined company A. Now thinking of joining B. On the fence about telling B's hiring manager the truth, that it's not really about the short term money, but more about longevity. Also company A has lot of traveling requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

I would go with whoever:

1- Pays more.

2- I "so far" liked.

Sponsorship talks could really change: Who says will sponsor might actually not, and who says will not sponsor (or waiting for business to reply) might actually do.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I know the sponsorship talks could change. That's the core of my worry. :(
Think going for the money (+ my interested company) makes sense sort of.